# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, oop

I am getting the following compiler errors with the below code snippet:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property

in line 5, and

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or
>   property

in line 1 here at `checker` in `ThreadStart`:

```
public Thread tC = new Thread(new ThreadStart(checker));

public static void checker()
{
    if (CheckServerState()) LabelWrite(true, Label1);
    else LabelWrite(false,Label1);
}
```

Could anyone please explain why I get those errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first code snippet I presume that `Label1` is the name of a class, not the name of a variable. You need to instantiate an object of that class. Then you can pass that object to your `LabelWrite()` method

```
public static void checker()
{
    Label1 label = new Label1();
    if (CheckServerState()) LabelWrite(true, label);
    else LabelWrite(false,label);
}
```

---

The second compiler error means that you can't reference to the method `checker()` when you are assigning the new Thread object to `tC` in a field initializer.

You need to do that in a constructor:

```
public Thread tC;

public MyClass()
{
    tC = new Thread(new ThreadStart(checker));

}

public void checker()
{
    if (CheckServerState()) LabelWrite(true, Label1);
    else LabelWrite(false,Label1);
}
```